# How would you initialize inline a variable where the type is a function?

Tags: swift

Here's a common variable, for example in network code.

```
private var callback: ((_ blah: String?) -> ())
```

Of course, you can't do that because there's no initializer.

This is easy enough

```
private var callback: ((_ blah: String?) -> ())?
```

then of course it's just

```
private var callback: ((_ blah: String?) -> ())? = nil
```

for the initializer.

But how to initialize this?

```
private var callback: ((_ blah: String?) -> ())
```

So it's going to be something like

```
private var callback: ((_ blah: String?) -> ()) = ( (_ String?){ return }() )
```

but I can not at all figure it out.

How to?

---

*Unrelated* Here's a common example, re the question asked about why callbacks are private

```
class SomeWorker {

  public func someLong(networkThing: String,
                      onMain: @escaping (_ foundIt: Blah?) -> () ) {
    
      callback = onMain
      loopForALongTimeDoingStuff( ... )
  }

  private var callback ...
```

Comment: Question: It you set it optional, don't make it private, and if you do: `let object = Object(); object.callBack = ...`, how would you write the "..."? Same here. It's a more "common" context that you might have already encounter, and you should do the same.

Comment: Cheers @Larme I don't totally follow you, sorry. It's completely normal that (in some cases) you want and need a variable to be non-optional.  And it's completely normal that (in other cases) you want and need a variable to be optional.  If you're saying that "all variables should be optional", that's totally wrong I'm afraid. Secondly I'm not sure what you mean about private. For example in the typical case of (as I mention) the usual networking code, it of course has to be private. (You may be thinking more of a delegate situation.)  I'll put in an example ...

Comment: That's not what I meant. I was looking for an iOS SDK sample, but didn't think of one. My suggestion was, you might have encountered already an example, where you do `let myObject = MyObject(); myObject.onSuccess = { ... }`, and it's a closure. What I meant is that's it's the same implementation in your case.

Comment: I don't really follow. Anyway, it's a commonplace that you want a variable to be private (for many various reasons).

Comment: It's not about private/public, it's more about: You don't have anywhere in your code `= {... }` for a closure? That's what I meant. You might have already used somewhere else that, and the way it's written, it's the same.

Comment: Hi again @Larme . Pls look at the example code I pasted in the bottom of the question.  The ubiquitous example is `api.login(email: e, pass: p) { token, status in blah }`  In swift you can have a trailing closure and you don't even have to bother typing the argument name.  This sort of pattern `let object = Object(); object.callBack = ...` you mention is totally unrelated.  (Note fwiw in my example code there, the call back "callback" is the cb for ***that one particular function*** (someLong). A class like SomeWorker may have dozens of such network calls (or, whatever they are).

Comment: And indeed per your original question, "callback" in the example would of course be private. (What you are mentioning is more along the lines of a delegate, you may be thinking of that sort of pattern.)

Comment: Again, it's not about private/public, I know what you mean. It's about closure initialization. Here are more explanation of what I meant: https://pastebin.com/qvhNwuvh because I thought you were too much focused on "inline". As I gave an Alamofire use sample too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize a non-optional variable with a default value of the declared type, an empty closure

- If the closure doesn't have a parameter it's just a pair of braces

  ```
  var callback: () -> Void = { }
  ```
- If there are one or more parameters you have to add underscore characters for each parameter and the `in` keyword

  ```
  var callback: (String) -> Void = { _ in }
  var callback: (String, Bool) -> Void = { _,_ in }
  ```

Notes:

- Parameter labels with an underscore as external label are outdated since Swift 3.
- A (private) callback in the same class/struct is also outdated in times of `async/await`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do:

```swift
private var callback: (String?) -> Void = { _ in }
```

and if you really needed the param name there you could do:

```swift
private var callback: (_ blah: String?) -> Void = { _ in }
```

Using type inference is also a possibility:

```swift
private var callback = { (blah: String?) in }
// will infer the return type to be void
```

But like the comments suggest, these are just a preferences.

You could also use implicitly unwrapped optionals which will implicitly initialise to nil. This way, you wouldn't need to actually fill the contents of the closure. However, if you use it without initialisation you'll crash.

```swift
typealias Callback = (String?) -> Void

private var callback: Callback!  // no need for the initialiser now
```

Comment: Great stuff TY TY. i can't quite seem to make that work in my setting but handy

Comment: @Fattie that's strange because these declarations should work anywhere. What error was being emitted?

Comment: you're right, I'm checking my other work!  it might be that the argument (where it's "incoming" as a closure) has to be the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
private var callback: ((_ blah: String?) -> ()) = { blah in }
```

Comment: @Fattie Fair enough. It wasn't its own answer at the time, and the unused variable name was a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @burnsi' fantastic answer.  It's possible the best idiom is

```
private var callback: ((_ playableUrl: URL?) -> ()) = { _ in return }
```

or even

```
private var callback: ((_ playableUrl: URL?) -> ()) = { _ in return () }
```